# Postgres - ERROR: Execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway

Tags: pgadmin

While executing one query I am facing the error message displayed below.

**Error: execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway**

can any one tell me how to abort this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

sometimes what happens when you are executing a query multiple times in pgAdmin, when the previous query is not yet completed or something this kind of error comes..

Comment: so the solution would be ... ?

Comment: Uncle Ben, my current solution is to kill the pgadmin query tab and open another one...

Comment: happens often when you "Stop" a running query and then try to run a new one, but the previous one hasn't actually been killed yet.

Answer (score 4):

Please check if autocomplete is enabled? It happens a lot when auto-suggest is on. To switch off autocomplete go to `File > Preferences > Query Tool > Auto Completion` and disable Autocomplete on Key press.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when POSTGRE SQL is running a process and often the query is taking time, So you without stopping or closing run another process in the sab tab.

Solution is copy all the queries and close the tab, open new tab and run the query again.

Comment: Or you could always stop/cancel the query process and run again

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue, fixed it by change connection from sync to async, hope it helps.

from another post:
Synchronous basically means that you can only execute one thing at a time. Asynchronous means that you can execute multiple things at a time and you don't have to finish executing the current thing in order to move on to next one.

Comment: didn't you mean to say: change from sync to async? not async to sync.

Comment: Why wouldn't explain how you changed the connection from async to sync?

Comment: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/async.html